# Removing a Galera node from a cluster and add new node in it

Tags: mariadb, replication, galera

I want to remove the previously added node (node2). and add a new node instead of it (node3). The new node is the snapshot of the previous node (node2). It is working fine, why? I didn't change any setting in node1. (I mean, how node1 knows that to use node3 node too).

Comment: How was the "snapshot" taken?  Where did you spell out "node3"?

Comment: hey, @RickJames the snapshot was taken through the digital ocean.

Comment: I didn't change in the new server "node3". it was working fine maybe because it was the copy of node2. but the question is how node1 comes to knows to replicate in new node3 also.

Comment: If the snapshot is a copy of the disk, then no one (at least not Galera) can tell the difference between node2 and node3.  The "new" nodes will act just like the "old" one and pick up where it left off.

Comment: yes, but the IP of the new node is something else (different than the node2). and If I change anything on node1 (creating Database), it is replicating on node3 also. How node1 could come to know about new node node3?